# Display Categories with Image in Multiple Pages of Homepage - Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7

In my Customization , i have more than 100 categories under Default Category so I want to Display all the categories in multiple pages with images Homepage - Magento.

Im Using the below code :

```
   <div class="category-products">
   <ul class="products-grid">
   <?php
$_categories=$this->getCurrentChildCategories();
if($_categories->count()):
$categorycount = 0;
foreach ($_categories as $_category):
if($_category->getIsActive()):
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
$catName = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
if ($categorycount == 0){
$class = "first";
}
elseif ($categorycount == 3){
$class = "last";
}
else{
$class = "";
}
 ?>
<li class="item <?=$class?>">
  <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo   $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $_category->getImageUrl() ?>" width="100" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" /></a>
   <h2><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a></h2>
  </li>
 <?php
endif;
if($categorycount == 3){
$categorycount = 0;
echo "</ul>\n\n<ul class=\"products-grid\">";
}
else{
$categorycount++;
}
   endforeach;
   endif;
   ?>
  </ul>
    </div>
```

In this code im just getting only product with images but not in proper manner (not aligned)
please anyone query me how to  **Display all the categories in multiple pages with images Homepage .**

Answer (score 0):

To display in Multiple page you will need to use some pagination techniques ,

to display the product categories do refer

[How to create Categories Grid (list) with images](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/how_to_create_categories_grid_list_with_images)

Comment: Just now tried on a 1.8 installation with sample data works fine . Can you post the error or a SS

Comment: Browse Products

    getIsActive()): ?> 
    Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\navigation\subcategory_listing.phtml on line 9

Comment: Im using Magento 1.7.0.2

Comment: <? foreach ($_categories as $_category):?>
    <? if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
    <?php $cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()); ?>
    <?php $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer'); ?>
    <?php $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category); ?>
    <? if($_imageUrl=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()):?>